# Proof of big-O notation

Tags: proof-writing, computer-science, education

Prove the following:

1. If f is a polynomial of degree $d$, then $f(n)=O(n^{d})$.
2. For every $d \in N, n^{d} = O(e^{n})$

Intuitively, it makes sense to me that for the first one, growth order depends on the term with the highest power and for the second one, exponential growth grows faster than anything else.  I'm not quite sure how to prove this, though.  I tried to use induction on the first one but I ended up just making a circular argument.

Comment: what doe you have to proof? how is $f(n)=O(n^{d})$ defined ?

Comment: I think that's partly why I'm confused.  The first point sort of looks like it's just asking for the definition of O notation for a polynomial, but I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to do more than just state a definition.  I guess I'm just kind of at a loss; I know how to use O notation in practice but this proof thing has thrown me off.
Also, whoever fixed my formatting, thanks.  LaTex wasn't going to happen from my phone!

Comment: For a stronger result, a proof of the theta bound for the first part of the question can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932619/how-to-prove-the-theta-notation/932687

Comment: As a hint to the second question, notice that $n^d = e^{d \ln(n)}$. If you can prove that $d \ln(n) \le n$ for arbitrarily large $n$, then you attain the result.

Answer (score 2):

1. Given two real valued functions *f* and *g*:
   $$f(n)=O(g(n))$$
   If $c>0$ and $n_0>0$: $f(n) \geq cg(n) \geq 0, \forall n\geq n_0$

From [the definition](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/class/02713-s13/lectures/lec06-bigoh2.pdf) it follows that for $n \geq 0$

$$a_0n^d + a_1n^{d-1} + a_2n^{d-2} + ... + a_d \leq |a_0|n^d + |a_1|n^{d-1} + |a_2|n^{d-2} + ... + |a_d|$$

$$\leq |a_0|n^d + |a_1|n^{d} + |a_2|n^{d} + ... + |a_d|n^{d}$$
$$\leq n^d(|a_0| + |a_1| + |a_2| + ... + |a_d|)$$
Let $c=|a_0| + |a_1| + |a_2| + ... + |a_d|$ and $n_0=1$
$$\Rightarrow g(n)\equiv n^d$$
$$\Rightarrow f(n)\equiv O(n^d)$$

Comment: f(n)≥cg(n) is wrong. It should be f(n)<=cg(n).